# Unable to update CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7, update

I had a perfectly working CentOS 7. Then, while installing some programs (and unfortunately I am unable to backtrace it) it seems the xorg and xorgxrdp conflicted with some RHEL repository and I couldn't update xrdp/xorgxrdp.

Then, on this site, I luckily found a way to go around it and performed the following steps to get the xrdp working again.

```
sudo yum -y install https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/x/xorgxrdp-0.2.9-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

sudo yum install xrdp

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
sudo systemctl start xrdp
```

Now, even though my RDP session from Win to Linux works, the bigger problem remains which is that I am unable to update. How do I go around fixing this?

Pls see the error below:

```
sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftpmirror.your.org
 * centosplus: ftpmirror.your.org
 * elrepo: ord.mirror.rackspace.com
 * epel: ord.mirror.rackspace.com
 * extras: ftpmirror.your.org
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: muug.ca
 * updates: ftpmirror.your.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package xorgxrdp.x86_64 0:0.2.9-1.el7 will be updated
---> Package xorgxrdp.x86_64 0:0.2.10-4.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.4 for package: xorgxrdp-0.2.10-4.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: xorgxrdp-0.2.10-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.4
           Installed: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.6.el7_6.x86_64 (@updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.6.el7_6
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-3.el7
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.el7
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.1.el7
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.2.el7_6.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.2.el7_6
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.3.el7_6.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1-5.3.el7_6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can someone please help me in fixing this? from what I am reading, it seems the RHEL 7.6 is conflicting with another version? However, I do have EPEL enabled.

```
sudo yum repolist all | grep enabled
base/7/x86_64                                   CentOS-7 - Bas enabled: 10,017+2
centosplus/7/x86_64                             CentOS-7 - Plu enabled:      103
cr/7/x86_64                                     CentOS-7 - cr  enabled:        0
docker-ce-stable/x86_64                         Docker CE Stab enabled:       52
elrepo                                          ELRepo.org Com enabled:      124
epel/x86_64                                     Extra Packages enabled:   13,367
extras/7/x86_64                                 CentOS-7 - Ext enabled:      435
rpmfusion-free-updates/x86_64                   RPM Fusion for enabled:      247
updates/7/x86_64                                CentOS-7 - Upd enabled: 2,484+16
virtualbox/7/x86_64                             Oracle Linux / enabled:       70
```

Comment: This is exactly the same issue as in the linked question, and exactly the same answer applies to you.

Comment: Mike, that only applies to xrdp. However, at this point, I am unable to update the machine period. The reply suggests how to get around for the xrdp install (which I used and successfully did), however, the system update is a no go. I am 1 day old here, so I apologize if I am not looking at the right reply.

Comment: You mean xorgxrdp? The issue is still the same. Nothing has changed. You could use `--skip-broken` as suggested to skip the packages until CentOS 7.7 is available.